# Create Relative Path Using System.Uri

Tags: c#

I am converting absolute file-system path to relative path using following code.

```
public static void Main(string[] args)
{
    System.Uri uri1 = new Uri(@"C:\Users\301591\Downloads\My Pics\abcd.jpg", true);
    System.Uri uri2 = new Uri(@"C:\Users\301591\", true);
    Uri relativeUri = uri2.MakeRelativeUri(uri1);
    Console.WriteLine(relativeUri.ToString());
}
```

The result I am getting is /Downloads/My Pics/abcd.jpg

but compiler is throwing a warning, constructor I am using is marked obsolete.

```
Uri testUri=new Uri("string path","flag to remove escape sequences");
```

Is there any other way to create relative path with showing escape sequence in the result?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found the solution.

It is

```
Console.WriteLine(Uri.UnescapeDataString(relativeUri.ToString()));
```

Answer (score 1):

Uri.MakeRelative method is obsolete as per MSDN : http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.uri.makerelative.aspx

So Urii.MakeRelativeUri cannot through obsolete warning http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.uri.makerelativeuri

So please carry on using http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.uri.makerelativeuri with Cosntructor new Uri(@"C:\Users\301591\");